# Roots of polynomials in field of prime characteristic p

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$, and let $\alpha \in F$. Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ be such that $f(\alpha) = 0$. Apparently, we have $f(\alpha^p) = 0$. This was mentioned but not proved in my lectures. Can someone explain why please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$. Since $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $a_i^p=a_i$ for each $i$. Also, since $F$ has characteristic $p$, you have the so called freshman's dream, that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$ for $x,y\in F$. So

$$
f(\alpha^p)=\sum a_i\alpha^{pi}=\sum a_i^p\alpha^{pi}=\sum (a_i\alpha^i)^p=\left(\sum a_i\alpha^i\right)^p=0^p=0.
$$